# 401 Error on Blackberry Device

Tags: iis, blackberry, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint instance serving as our Extranet to our salesforce - communicating over HTTPS. All sales agents have a Blackberry device, but none can access our Extranet.

In IIS, we only have ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication enabled, but the BB device doesnt even prompt for credentials, it just receives a 401 error.

Needless to say, the site is browsable on other devices (PC, tablet, iPhone..), so it seems to be something specific to BB settings - or thats my inclination. Anyone have any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot\resolve?

I should add.. I downloaded the BlackBerry emulator for my PC, and that too has the same issue, so I dont think it's a BlackBerry service setting.. but something with how the device is attempting to connect\authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the answer (apparently the Google machine is running much better today than it was yesterday ;)

Blackberry doesnt support Windows Authentication since the browser is too old.  I had to turn on Basic Authentication, which isnt recommended unless your running over SSL.. which fortunately I am.  Found the answer here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273