# Http 401 along with Http 500 in blackberry app development

Tags: oauth, blackberry, http-headers, http-status-code-401

I am developing a Blackberry Application With Oauth Webservice. 
While I am sending a GET request, I am getting HTTP 401 status code first 
although i am sending authorization header properly.When i am invoking same webservice 
again its giving HTTP 500 error.
I am confused to, to trace the error, whether Its from client side or server error.
I am running MDS simulator too.
Please help me regarding this.

Here us my code snippet:

```
private HttpConnection HttpRequestCreate(boolean post) throws IOException,MalformedURIException,PINException, net.rim.device.api.crypto.InvalidKeyException,UnsupportedEncodingException,net.rim.device.api.crypto.NoSuchAlgorithmException ,IllegalStateException,NullPointerException,IllegalArgumentException, CryptoTokenException, CryptoUnsupportedOperationException
{
String Authhdr=null;    

uthScheme authScheme = new AuthScheme.Builder(HTTPVerb,URI,Date,Keys)
.setContentMD5(ContentMD5)
.setContentType(ContentType)
.build();

Authhdr = authScheme.getAuthorizedHeader();

if(Authhdr ==null)
    throw new NullPointerException("Authorization header cannot be null.Please check whether authorization header is properly generated or not.");              
HttpConnection ConnectionHandle = null; 
ConnectionHandle=(javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection)
Connector.open(URI, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
ConnectionHandle.setRequestMethod(HTTPVerb);
ConnectionHandle.setRequestProperty("Date",Date);
ConnectionHandle.setRequestProperty("Host",Host);
ConnectionHandle.setRequestProperty("Authorization", Authhdr);
if(ContentLength!=null)
    ConnectionHandle.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",ContentLength);

if(ContentMD5!=null)
    ConnectionHandle.setRequestProperty("Content-MD5",ContentMD5);   

if(ContentType!=null)
    ConnectionHandle.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",ContentType);        

return ConnectionHandle;                            
}
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This could help you
[401 Error on Blackberry Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297154/401-error-on-blackberry-device)
or there may be TLS 1.2 issue. Because apparently bb has some issue with non TLS 1.0 connections